# How to write conditional ruby code to show in form of .arb file (Active Admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, arbre

I want to fetch the Attachment Model's attribute name(pdf_file.file_name) based on condition (if..else). But I am not familiar with Arbe Syntex and cant show the outputs in view.

I am rendering a partial file from my `active_admin` class.

The code in my `_test.arb` file

```
f.has_many :course_pdf_attachments, allow_destroy: true do |attachment|
  if attachment.object.pdf_file.present?
   'Uploaded PDF:'
   link_to attachment.object.pdf_file.filename.upcase,
           attachment.object.pdf_file_url
  end
  attachment.input :pdf_file, as: :file
end
```

The output I am getting in the view is only the `input_filed` not the value that I'm trying to show in the conditions.

How to write this code so that my values are visible in the view?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got bitten by this in the past as well. `link_to` is a rails views helper, using this inside `arbres` output capturing doesn't work well, unless you enclose it in a  span like so:

```
span do
  link_to ...
end
```

Another way, this is more arbre-like, is to spell out the `a` tag and say:

```
if attachment.object.pdf_file.present?
  span { 'Uploaded PDF:' }
  a(href: attachment.object.pdf_file_url) do
    attachment.object.pdf_file.filename.upcase
  end
end
```

Let me know if it works.